# Exporting csv files with autoFit and changing the TabName of csv file

Tags: php, symfony

I am using php with symfony2  to export the data in csv format using the following steps :

```
public function exportAction(Request $request) {

    $data = array("data" => "test");

    $format = $request->getRequestFormat();

    if ($format == "csv") {
        $response = $this->render('PrototypeBundle:Prototype:export.' . $format . '.twig', array('data' => $data));
        $filename = "export_".date("Y_m_d_His").".csv";
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename);

        return $response;
    } else if ($format == "json") {
        return new Response(json_encode($data));
    }
}
```

How can i set the autoFit for all the columns in csv file and how can i change the tabName of the csv sheet.In my case i only have one sheet in my csv file and would like to specify dynamic sheetName for each csv export workflow.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't.  csv is just simple text and has no auto fit or tab names.  You are viewing it with a spreadsheet (probably excel?) which gives the appearance of auto fit and tab names but they are not in the csv file.  If you want additional formatting then you need to generates actual spreadsheet files using prehaps the xlsx format.  This library can get you going: http://phpoffice.github.io/index.html

Comment: how about the tabName ,can i change that in my csv export

Comment: If be tabName you mean the name that shows up on the tabs for individual sheets then the answer is no.  Take a moment and research what a csv file actually is.